# Second order difference is bound by maximum of the second derivative

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

$$f\in C^{2}(\mathbb{R})\textrm{ such that }\left | f''(x) \right |\leq M\: \: \forall x\in \mathbb{R}.\\
\textrm{Prove that }\frac{\left | f(x+h)+f(x-h)-2f(x) \right |}{h^{2}}\leq M\: \: \forall x\in \mathbb{R}$$
I have tried mean value theorem and other standard analysis results but have made no progress. Kindly help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $\int_x^{x+h}f'(t)dt-\int_x^{x+h}f'(t-h)dt=f(x+h)+f(x-h)-2f(x)$. Apply MVT to $f'(t)-f'(t-h)$.

Answer (score 1):

For fixed $x$ consider the function
$$
g(h) = f(x+h) + f(x-h) - 2f(x) \, .
$$
Then use Taylor's theorem in the form
$$
 g(h) = g(0) + hg'(0) + \frac 12 h^2 g''(c)
$$
for some $c$ between $0$ and $h$, and note that $g(0) = g'(0) = 0$. This gives
$$
 \frac{f(x+h) + f(x-h) - 2f(x)}{h^2} = \frac {f''(x+c) + f''(x-c)}2
$$
and the desired estimate follows immediately.

*Remarks:*

- Only the existence of the second derivative of $f$ is needed for this conclusion, not its continuity.
- One even has
  $$
  \frac{f(x+h) + f(x-h) - 2f(x)}{h^2} = f''(\xi)
  $$
  for some $\xi \in (x-h, x+h)$. That follows from above calculations and the [mean value property for derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis)), or from the general result [Is there a mean value theorem for higher order differences?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/496067/is-there-a-mean-value-theorem-for-higher-order-differences).